# Вращение изображения кнопки при нажатии на нее

Tags: kotlin, анимация, compose-desktop

Как сделать вращение иконки на 360° при нажатии на кнопку.
В интернете нашёл только бесконечное вращение при запуске программы.

```kotlin
    val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val angle by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 360f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            tween(1000, easing = LinearEasing)
        )
    )
        IconButton(
            onClick = {

            },
            modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 5.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Refresh,
                contentDescription = null,
                tint = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .rotate(angle)
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вместо бесконечной анимации используйте [`Animatable`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/value-based#animatable).

При создании объекта `Animatable` задается начальное значение. Далее, анимация запускается с помощью функции `animateTo`. Вернуть в начальное положение без анимации можно с помощью функции `snapTo`.

Так как `animateTo` и `snapTo` являются suspend-функциями, то их необходимо запускать внутри скоупа корутины:

```kotlin
private val animationSpec: AnimationSpec<Float> =
    tween(durationMillis = 2000, easing = EaseOutElastic)

@Composable
fun RotatingButton() {
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val angle = remember { Animatable(initialValue = 0f) }
    IconButton(
        onClick = {
            scope.launch {
                angle.snapTo(targetValue = 0f)
                angle.animateTo(targetValue = 360f, animationSpec)
            }
        },
    ) {
        Icon(
            modifier = Modifier.rotate(angle.value),
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Refresh,
            contentDescription = null,
        )
    }
}
```